# С++ запрос к веб-сайту

Tags: c++, get

Вообщем, все вожусь со своей не большой программой, понадобилось сделать GET запрос к сайту и получить ответ, в интернете куча способов, но в основном это больший класс\библиотеки, может есть какой нибудь иной способ?

Comment: А чем вас библиотеки-то не устраивают?

Comment: Мне не нужен весь спектор их возможностей, а лишь банальный запрос и ответ на него, я относительно не давно занимаюсь c++, допустим на том же php все это можно сделать 1 функцией...

Comment: >допустим на том же php все это можно сделать 1 функцией

@avengerweb ну вы и сравнили. На то он и php - язык, ориентированный на web-разработку. В плюсах все немножко по-другому. Штатных средств языка, насколько знаю, для этоо нет. Есть библиотеки. И полным их функционалом пользоваться не обязательно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать сокеты, я когда-то давно делал такое.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int sock;
struct sockaddr_in client;
int PORT = 80;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct hostent * host = gethostbyname("api.themoviedb.org");

    if ( (host == NULL) || (host->h_addr == NULL) ) {
        cout << "Error retrieving DNS information." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    bzero(&client, sizeof(client));
    client.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client.sin_port = htons( PORT );
    memcpy(&client.sin_addr, host->h_addr, host->h_length);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sock < 0) {
        cout << "Error creating socket." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    if ( connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sizeof(client)) < 0 ) {
        close(sock);
        cout << "Could not connect" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    stringstream ss;
    ss << "GET /3/movie/" << 550 << "?api_key=xxx HTTP/1.1\r\n"
       << "Host: api.themoviedb.org\r\n"
       << "Accept: application/json\r\n"
       << "\r\n\r\n";
    string request = ss.str();

    if (send(sock, request.c_str(), request.length(), 0) != (int)request.length()) {
        cout << "Error sending request." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    char cur;
    while ( read(sock, &cur, 1) > 0 ) {
        cout << cur;
    }

    return 0;
}
```